# Simple sildeshow/image-upload plugin?

Tags: plugins, uploads, images

What i need is either an easy-to-use slideshow with features like uploading and rezising images to fit, and displaying the slideshow in the template. (i want to be able to add it manually in the template)

I've been looking for one, but not many of them allows the user to upload images. Or the plugin itself is too complicated and has a ton of useless controls for the slideshow which can't be turned off.

So, if anyone knows a good simple slideshow, let me know.

Actually, it would be OK with an upload-plugin of some sort. Just a simple plugin that allows the user to upload and resize photos and save them in a folder. I can code the slideshow myself if needed. That would actually be the best way, but i can't seem to find that either.

Let me know if you know what i'm looking for.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Easing Slider is a great plugin that will accomplish what you want: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/easing-slider/

It let's you disable the controls as well.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [uBillBoard slider](http://codecanyon.net/item/ubillboard-premium-slider-for-wordpress/124783) out from CodeCanyon. It's a premium plugin ($20), but is extremely well done.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Do you know if it's possible to disable the slideshow controls (next/prev/pause etc)? I'm not really looking for anything advanced, so i'd prefer not paying for it. I'm sure what i need is somewhere out there.

Comment: I've used it before, but honestly don't remember. I'm pretty sure it is. Check the feature list. You're probably unlikely to find a free plugin that allows the capabilities you want.

Comment: I've been working on making a slideshow image uploader that adds images as attachments to posts and can be displayed as a slideshow. It's not easy, and if I do ever finish it, it will be a premium plugin for sure. It's been a hell of alot of work and a project I've been making for a year now.

Comment: Premium slideshow plugins are a HUGE amount of work. Believe me, I know. I just finished my own not too long ago. It does support disabling / enabling all different kinds of controls and such.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the [Easing Slider](https://wordpress.org/plugins/easing-slider/) plugin and I am sure it's what you need for your task, or you might also try Nivo Slider.